# React: Capture image in messenger webview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, camera, facebook-messenger

I have a small react app (for mobile only) with image capture tag to click image from camera only (block file picker dialog)

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onChange={this.handleUploadImage} />`

I'm using it to capture image from android and ios browsers.

This tag works fine in chrome for android and safari for ios, but when it opens up in facebook messenger's webview then it doesnot open the camera, instead it opens up file picker dialog in android.

So **is there any way to open up camera in facebook messenger's webview and block access to file picker dialog**?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: webview just sees input type file as upload. i think you might need to add dependecies or create a module. some dependencies available:
1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html5-camera-photo
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-camera

Comment: @AbhishekAnand seems like a good idea, let me check it out. Thanks for a heads up buddy

Comment: @AbhishekAnand can u frame an answer for it. Your comment has almost solved the problem, so i'll tag your answer as the correct answer

Comment: did it! thanks for coming after after the problem was solved. glad i could help you around @iamsaksham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you are trying to access camera with input type "file". While it works good in a browser, any webview of an application treats it as a tag for file input/upload.

What you need is to create a module which allows access to camera even in webview, and use that where you want it to. A camera module can be created using `getUserMedia() api`, also you can checkout `webrtc and webkit` for this.

Please check the support for `getUserMedia() api` in different browsers for better understanding. As `it dont work in chrome/firefox for ios` as of now.

You can also use open source dependencies available, some of which are:

1. [react html 5 camera](https://npmjs.com/package/react-html5-camera-photo)
2. [react-camera](https://npmjs.com/package/react-camera)

Comment: I'm curious, does getUserMedia work in webviews for you. I'm trying to get something similar to work but webviews in the messenger app don't seem to display the pop-up asking for camera access. Tried with https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ for example without success...